# Dealing with Large Legends in R Plots - Complicated Heatmap Example

Tags: r, plot, legend, heatmap

I'm working on a really complicated heatmap figure in R.  `heatmap.2` from the `gplots` package is not enough for me, because I want multiple sidebar annotations, such as the `heatmap.3` function permits: https://www.biostars.org/p/18211/

Here's my specific plot so far:

[image]

When I have multiple sidebar annotations on this heatmap, though, they need to be properly labeled with a legend.  The legend quickly becomes unwieldy and starts bleeding off the plot or into other labels on the plot, depending on where I choose to place the legend.

I've tried using the `ncols` option when placing the legend at the bottom of the plot but the legend contains information about several factors worth of metadata, and I want a separate column in the legend to denote each sidebar's worth of metadata.  As far as I know there is no option in the `legend` command to permit this functionality, so I'm interested in hearing potential ways around this.

Alternatively, I am also open to the idea of simply generating a legend image with R separately if anyone knows how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: That is a LOT of information for a single plot... is that going in a paper or on a gigantic poster? Just my 2¢...If nobody can read it maybe you should consider doing it in a completely different way... for instance could you group the labels into some meaningful class and then report them separately as a table?

Comment: Thanks for your 2 cents.  The intended audience is experts in the field, so they can read these plots like a children's book.  In addition, the plot is interactive as part of a Shiny app, so one would have the functionality to drop metadata sidebars in and out of the heatmap as they saw fit.

Comment: Oh, that wasn't what I meant! I meant if nobody can read it in the sense that those labels are way too small!

Comment: Just a small comment, for a heatmap containing so many annotations, a title (e.g. Age, Sex) for each legend will help to correspond between legend and the annotation. I am also developing an package `ComplexHeatmap` (on bioconductor now) which can make complex heatmaps, but it cannot plot the density distribution as in the top left in your figure. Also there is a `ColorMapping` class in the package which can generate a legend as a `grob` object but I don't know whether it can help you.